# how can I get the width of a child of the button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

how can i get a child's width in react and typescript? something like children.width?

```
{loading ? <Spinner size='small' /> : children}
```

I need to leave the button with the same size regardless of showing the children or the spinner, but the reference of the width must be the children, it is dynamic

Comment: What is ````children````?  We have no idea what it's referencing.

Comment: children is reactNode, but I can define it as a string if necessary, I just wanted to know how I get the width of it

Comment: You cant unless its already been loaded, by doing this you are saying dont load until loading has finished. maybe if you were using a display property like hide until finished loading but that defeats the point

Comment: <Button>children</Button>

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can leave the button when displaying the loading of the same size as the children?